# In Navcontroller I am getting unresolved issue for getViewModelStoreOwner

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I am trying to initiate viewModel using nav graph and factory. I am trying to compile following code

```
 private val navController by lazy { findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment) }

val viewModelProvider = ViewModelProvider(
        navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.navigation),
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)
    )
```

However, I am getting unresolved reference for getViewModelStoreOwner. I am following this https://www.raywenderlich.com/4332831-navigation-component-for-android-part-2-graphs-and-deep-links tutorial.

I am using following dependencies

```
def nav_version = "2.3.2"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: How are you getting your `navController` instance?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have updated the question . Please check.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am getting like this  private val navController by lazy { findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment) }